# Querying the Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table named Order

```
-______________________
|Order_id | customer_id |
|_________|_____________|
|     1   |    a        |
|     2   |    b        |
|     3   |    c        |
|     4   |    a        |
|_________|_____________|
```

I needed a query to Find the Customer_id which contains the list of more than one orders and to store those contents in a new table

Comment: What "contents" do you mean? The customer_ids that have more than one order? Please edit example output (to be assigned) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Find the Customer_id which contains the list of more than one orders

So just the `COUNT()` or rows for any given `customer_id`?  Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS order_count, customer_id FROM test GROUP BY customer_id
```

This would return:

```
order_count    customer_id
--------------------------
2              a
1              b
1              c
```

If you want to further reduce the results to only those with more than one order, just filter on that.  My SQL is a little rusty, but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS order_count, customer_id FROM order GROUP BY customer_id) AS order_counts
WHERE order_count > 1
```

Which would yield:

```
order_count    customer_id
--------------------------
2              a
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL would create a new table with customers more than 1 orders

```
CREATE TABLE Multiple_Orders AS
   SELECT order_id, customer_id, COUNT(*) AS order_cnt FROM order 
   GROUP BY customer_id
   HAVING order_cnt > 1
```

Comment: Since order_id is not single-valued per customer_id, you should not be selecting it.